# How do I configure the Hyper-V virtual switch to share internet without bridging on the host machine?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, wds, mdt

I'm setting up windows deployment services for LiteTouch Deployments in my home but what I realized was that if I take my actual LAN NIC that is connected to the internet and bridge it to the Hyper-V virtual switch, the VMs that utilize that virtual switch will get internet(which I want so that I can perform Windows Updates on them to get them up to date)but then when I try to PXE boot on my machines I get the error "no boot filename received, exiting boot agent".

If I remove the bridge then I can get LiteTouch to boot fine.

OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new internal network in Hyper-V-settings for virtual switches.

A corresponding virtual NIC will show up in your Hyper-V-Hosts network-settings.

On your physical connection, you can then share your internet connection with that virtual NIC using normal internet connection sharing.

You should be aware that this will enable a second DHCP-server in your virtual-machine-network which you very likely do not want. You need to configure a static IP for your new virtual NIC to disable this DHCP-server.

Comment: So I would configure a static IP for the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" in the host server network connections? Or else where.

Comment: Okay so I've done as directed but I can't get a new VM to PXE network boot. Any troubleshooting tips? I shared my physical NIC's internet connection and set a static IP on the new virtual switch but no go. I get "PXE-E18: Server response timeout".